# Problems with port forwarding using cable modem/router combo

Tags: networking, router, port-forwarding

so recently I tried port forwarding and it didn't work using my public ip **77.77.2xx.1xx** to connect to it didn't work at all. In the router status I found a ip adress which I assume is my private ip **100.64.1xx.6** and tried connecting to the port using that address it worked but since it's a private address it won't work out of my network :/. Any help, can I get in contact with someone? I am using isp's provided cable modem/router combo Cisco EPC3925

Comment: Your ISP is likely using [Carrier Grade NAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carrier-grade_NAT). Please read [Alternatives to Port Forwarding & NAT](https://portforward.com/help/alt-to-pf.htm): "There are four major problems that you may run into that would require alternatives to port forwarding. " ...

Comment: MY isp said that it doesn't block any ports and that port forwarding should work any help?